# Santizing input in subclassed string does not work as expected

Tags: string, python-2.7, replace

I had a use case where I wanted to sanitize the string given as input to the str class. In other words, delete control characters in the string.

I tried this

```
[hamartin@Guvny bin]$ ipython
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:30:34) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: class LogString(str):
   ...:     def __init__(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         nstr = msg.replace('\xc2', '')
   ...:         nstr = nstr.replace('\xa0', ' ')
   ...:         super(LogString, self).__init__(nstr, *args, **kwargs)
   ...:         

In [2]: repr(LogString('Testing this out'))
Out[2]: "'Testing\\xc2\\xa0this\\xc2\\xa0out'"
```

I know the replace work for this specific situation.

```
[hamartin@Guvny bin]$ ipython
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:30:34) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: i = 'Testing this out'

In [2]: repr(i)
Out[2]: "'Testing\\xc2\\xa0this\\xc2\\xa0out'"

In [3]: i = i.replace('\xc2', '')

In [4]: repr(i.replace('\xa0', ' '))
Out[4]: "'Testing this out'"

In [5]:
```

I am not storing the original string anywhere except in a temporary variable. I am replacing the characters before passing it up the tree. Why does the created object have the original string in it instead of the "sanitized" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Python are inmutable. Since you're subclassing `str`, you can't change the value once it was supplied. Instead, override the `__new__` static method:

```
class LogString(str):
    def __new__(cls, msg):
        nstr = msg.replace('\xc2', '')
        nstr = nstr.replace('\xa0', ' ')
        return str.__new__(cls, nstr)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tested this out and it work. The documentation I found on __new__ also confirms what you say. I still don't understand why my example doesn't work. Is the __new__ method executed before __init__ msg and from that moment msg is immutable? Which is the reason to overload the __new__ method so that str's __new__ method won't run? If what I wrote is correct, does the __new__ method for str do anything usefull that I might want to replicate in my method?

Comment: @Mogget That's right, the `__new__` method is executed even before the object is created, while `__init__` is actually the first function of the instance that is executed. That's why the former is a static method, you're changing the string right before the object is created. Not sure what do you mean with the last question, you're calling the original str's `__new__` method in the last line!